# Preserve CSS transform property after removing the class

Tags: html, css, web, css-animations, css-transforms

**Is it possible to preserve a CSS property (including variables) after removing a class that modifies them ?**

The problem is in the code below.
I want to preserve the transform property of the cyan box after removing the class `animation-slide-to-left` that slides the box to the left.
That is because when removing that `animation-slide-to-left` and adding the class `animation-slide-to-right` class, I want that new animation to start from where the old one ended.

**But the problem is when removing `animation-slide-to-left` the transform property resets and becomes equal to Its old value before adding that class.**

Note: I don't want to hard code the `transform` property at 0%, because there are a lot of animations, and I am searching for a way that automatically solve the problem without JAVASCRIPT.

(expand the snippet result to full page too see the example)

```js
const box = document.querySelector (".animated");

function leftclicked (){
  box.classList.remove ("animation-slide-to-right");
  box.classList.add ("animation-slide-to-left");
}

function rightclicked (){
  box.classList.remove ("animation-slide-to-left");
  box.classList.add ("animation-slide-to-right");
}
```

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
 animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-direction: normal;
 animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.animation-slide-to-left {
 animation-name: slide-to-left;
}

.animation-slide-to-right {
 animation-name: slide-to-right;
}


@keyframes slide-to-left {
  100%{
    transform: translate(-150%, -50%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-to-right {
  100%{
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center" style="width:300px; height: 300px; background-color: red;">

  <div class="center animated" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background-color:cyan;">
  </div>
  
  <button style="float:left;" onclick="leftclicked()">LEFT</button>
  <button style="float:right;" onclick="rightclicked()">RIGHT</button>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the starting position for each time you click on the buttons LEFT and RIGHT in the CSS keyframes, so that when the button is on the left side and click on the RIGHT button, it first sets the position to the left side (0%) before it animates to the right (100%) and vice-versa. This way it doesn't reset back to the center when clicking the buttons.

```js
const box = document.querySelector (".animated");

function leftclicked (){
  box.style.transform = 'translate(50%, -50%)';
  box.classList.remove ("animation-slide-to-right");
  box.classList.add ("animation-slide-to-left");
}

function rightclicked (){
  box.style.transform = 'translate(-150%, -50%)';
  box.classList.remove ("animation-slide-to-left");
  box.classList.add ("animation-slide-to-right");
}
```

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
 animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-direction: normal;
 animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.animation-slide-to-left {
 animation-name: slide-to-left;
}

.animation-slide-to-right {
 animation-name: slide-to-right;
}


@keyframes slide-to-left {
  100%{
    transform: translate(-150%, -50%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-to-right {
  100%{
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center" style="width:300px; height: 300px; background-color: red;">

  <div class="center animated" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background-color:cyan;">
  </div>
  
  <button style="float:left;" onclick="leftclicked()">LEFT</button>
  <button style="float:right;" onclick="rightclicked()">RIGHT</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to use JAVASCRIPT or hard code it in CSS as mentioned in the note. Thank you

Comment: @EEAH You're right, sorry about that! I edited it now so that the same behavior is happening in the CSS keyframes instead of Javascript.

Comment: The only problem now is that it resets to the left or right side the first time you click on the buttons, when the box is still in the center. I can't think of a solution to this at the moment, but maybe someone would have a suggestion. I hope I was able to help thus far, though :)

Comment: Thank you. But like said in the answer i added, JavaScript is used anyway. So it would be convenient to use JavaScript to achieve that behaviour

Comment: The previous JavaScript solution (before the edit) should be the answer

Comment: @EEAH "JavaScript is used anyway. So it would be convenient to use JavaScript to achieve that behaviour" That's exactly what I was thinking when I came up with the first solution ;) I'll change the answer back to the JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well It turns out that it is unnecessary to create such behaviour without JavaScript. 
Because if a CSS class is being replaced at runtime, we are already using JavaScript.
So the solution is to set the transform property in JavaScript after removing the old class and before adding the new class